# Flink add Task/JobManagers to cluster

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Regarding adding new Task/JobManagers to an existing running cluster the procedure can be found here (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/setup/cluster_setup.html#adding-jobmanagertaskmanager-instances-to-a-cluster).
However if we shutdown the cluster and start it again the information about the added hosts will be lost.
Is it safe practice that while adding the new host to the cluster to also update and save in parallel the "masters" and "slaves" configuration files on all nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely safe. The information from `masters` and `slaves` files are read only in starting scripts.